# 'The requested address is not valid in its context' while trying to connect to ArangoDB server on LAN

Tags: arangodb

I have two machines on LAN, I'd like to connect to AranoDB serve on one of them from another one.

The first one has an address 192.168.0.105, `arangod.conf`

```
[server]
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
storage-engine = auto
```

another one has an address 192.168.0.100 and `arangod.conf`

```
[server]
endpoint = tcp://192.168.0.105:8529
storage-engine = auto
```

ArangoDB on the first machine is working. When I try to start ArangoDB on the second machine, I see the following error:

```
2018-08-21T09:46:15Z [2724] INFO {authentication} Jwt secret not specified, generating...
2018-08-21T09:46:15Z [2724] INFO ArangoDB 3.3.12 [win64] 64bit, using build tags/v3.3.12-0-g225095d762, VPack 0.1.30, RocksDB 5.6.0, ICU 58.1, V8 5.7.492.77, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
2018-08-21T09:46:15Z [2724] INFO using storage engine mmfiles
2018-08-21T09:46:15Z [2724] INFO {cluster} Starting up with role SINGLE
2018-08-21T09:46:15Z [2724] INFO {authentication} Authentication is turned on (system only)
2018-08-21T09:46:18Z [2724] INFO using endpoint 'http+tcp://192.168.0.105:8529' for non-encrypted requests
2018-08-21T09:46:18Z [2724] ERROR {communication} unable to bind to endpoint 'http+tcp://192.168.0.105:8529': The requested address is not valid in its context
2018-08-21T09:46:18Z [2724] WARNING {communication} failed to open endpoint 'http+tcp://192.168.0.105:8529' with error: The requested address is not valid in its context
2018-08-21T09:46:18Z [2724] FATAL failed to bind to endpoint 'http+tcp://192.168.0.105:8529'. Please check whether another instance is already running using this endpoint and review your endpoints configuration.
```

I've already created rules in the windows firewall and in the router.
`Test-NetConnection` results are:

```
PS C:\Users\> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.0.105 -Port 8529
ComputerName     : 192.168.0.105
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.0.105
RemotePort       : 8529
SourceAddress    : 192.168.0.100
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you try here... connect with one server to another server? This is bound to fail. Don't you want to run a server on one machine and connect to it from another computer on the local network using `arangosh`? Or simply use the web interface?

The endpoint must be an address used by a network interface of your local computer. It can't be the address of another machine.

Setups like clusters require a lot more configuration (if done bare-metal).
For an overview of deployment modes including multi-machine setups you may want to check the documentation: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/deployment/